# Generate headings size with a recursive function in SASS

Tags: recursion, math, sass

I'm trying to write a recursive function with a multiplication factor. I'm not very experienced with recursion so there is the logic

```
x = foo
x+1 = foo * factor
x+2 = x+1 * factor
x+3 = x+2 * factor
.
.
.
y = x+n * factor
```

I'm struggling to find the math logic behind it, and I don't know if it is even possible to write it with a recursive function...

Comment: This would be quite possible. What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with? Have you looked up existing recursive functions to get an idea of how they work?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are those `+` signs meant to represent that the following number is a subscript, or is there another meaning? You added the `sass` tag but I see no relationship to `sass` in the question. Just what do you mean by "math logic"? Are you asking us to write a recursive function for you? If so, in which programming language? Please clarify.

Comment: I looked up on a few tutorial and articles about recursive function, but usually it is "basic" function on factorials and so on.  I want to generate a value based on a multiplication from the previous calculated value with a simple factor.

Comment: Ok I'll try with numbers then, lets image I want to generate headings font-size in sass. The logic starts with a root font-size of 16px, each time I increment to a bigger heading, the value is multiplied by 1.5. 

That said, here is what it should look like: 
p -> 16
h6 -> 16*1.5 = 24
h5 -> 24*1.5 = 36
etc.

Comment: Side note: You don't need recursion for that. It's a simple power `x * factor^n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I figured out I wasn't digging in the right direction. I extracted the factor the value of x from the equation and concentrated myself on the factor.

```
@function calculateFontSize($n) {
  @if $n == 1  {
    @return $headingSizeRatio;
  }
  @else {
    @return $headingSizeRatio * calculateFontSize($n - 1);
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  h#{7 - $i} {
    font-size: $base-font-size * calculateFontSize($i);
  }
}
```

It solved my issue. :)